# Add a custom option in Nautilus right click menu

Tags: linux, gnome-3, nautilus

When a user right-click on a folder in Nautilus, a menu appears. I want to add more options in that menu. I am using Gnome 3.

Is there any other way to customize that menu with command line? Actually I am making a Linux software and I want that these these options should be added when user installs the software.

Answer (score 12):

*This answer may be late, but it might be still useful.*

### **No any third party package(s) needed**

Write your own script and put it to: `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`

An example might be more clear:

If you want to add a Context Menu like `Open By VSCode`, you can create a file named `OpenByVScode.sh` with the content:

```
#!/bin/bash
code -n ${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS}
```

then, make it executable;

```
chmod 744 OpenByVScode.sh
```

Finally, cope/move this file to  `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`

The Context Menu is ready to use, which will be displayed under **script** submenu.

[image]

### **Codes explanation:**

First line: `#!/bin/bash`, to specify which language interpreter needed

Second line: `code -n ${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS}`

`code` is the `VSCode` default command, option `-n` means force to open in new window, on the contrary, it also has other option like `-r`, reuse the current windows, if the software is not open, this option will be the same like `-n`. For more, please check by `code --help`.

The variable `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` is defined by *nautilus*, like its name meaning, the path for the selected file or folder. It also has other three type of variables:

```
1. NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS   : newline-delimited URIs for selected files
2. NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI     : current location
3. NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_WINDOW_GEOMETRY : position and size of current window
```

For more info, please refer [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto)

Comment: Is there a way to add it to the menu, not in the sub-menu?

Comment: @EnthusiastiC Yes, use [FileManager-Actions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/filemanager-actions)

Comment: This package is no longer compatible with recent versions of Ubuntu

Comment: However, I found [good news](https://github.com/bassmanitram/actions-for-nautilus)

Answer (score 9):

You might want to use a [Nautilus script](http://g-scripts.sourceforge.net/), which doesn't require any additional installation like for [Nautilus Actions](http://www.nautilus-actions.org/).

In order to do that :

- copy your script in the folder `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`
- make sure it's *executable*.

It will then appear under the *Scripts* entry, from the right click context menu like below:

[image: Screenshot of Nautilus script context menu]

Answer (score 3):

### Nautilus Actions

We may define our own right-click context menu items with [**nautilus-actions**](https://web.archive.org/web/20161112011900/https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-actions/) [image: Install nautilus-actions]
.

- Run the *Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool* either from the Dash, or from a terminal with

  ```
  nautilus-actions-config-tool
  ```

[image]

- In the *Action* tab give your action a sensible label, e.g. *"Open in Terminator"* and choose to display this in the selection or the context menu.
- Next open the *Command* tab to enter the commands to run

[image]

- Give in the full path to your command (`/usr/bin/command_to_run`) and program options.
- After **logging out and in** again the right click context menu below will be displayed:

[image]

Comment: Is there any other way to do it with command line? Actually I am making a Linux software and I want that these these options should be added when user installs the software.

Comment: Is there a way to add it to the menu, not in the sub-menu?